# Looking for a optimal way to delete element from object[] java

Tags: java

I have an object array from which I want to delete a specific element based on it's index. I know two ways for it:

1. convert the object[] to a list and use remove function
2. set the element value to null and then make another object array and
   filter it

Is there any other optimal way to do it?

Comment: You should explain a bit more context: does the data structure have to be an array, how many times do you delete an item from the array vs how many times do you access it. Do you access elements by index, binary search, .. etc.

Comment: Use an ArrayList.

Answer (score 2):

- Create a new array of size `n-1`.
- Copy `0..index-1` elements from the old array to the new array.
- Copy `index+1..n` elements from the old array to the new array.

Use `java.lang.System.arraycopy(Object, int, Object, int, int)` for array copy operations.

This would be probably the most optimal way.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using streams could look like

```
Object[] myObject = {"foo", "bar", 42, 13, "doo"};
int indexToRemove = 3;
    
 Object[] result = IntStream.range(0, myObject.length)
                            .filter(i -> i != indexToRemove)
                            .mapToObj(i -> myObject[i])
                            .toArray();
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use Iterator  to remove the element in list.
Example code:

```
String[] array = {"one", "two", "three"};
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(array));
Iterator<String> it = list.iterator();
int index = 0;
while (it.hasNext())
{

    String next = it.next();
    if (index == 1)
    {
        it.remove();
    }

    index++;
}
```